# What is this flag with a red 6-pointed star in a red crescent on white ground?

Tags: germany, flag

I'm watching a documentary about the right-wing rise in Germany

Here they are speaking about a bar called ''Die Patriotische Bar'' and they happend to have some flags on the ceiling.

I couldn't understand what flag is the one on the left, it has a crescent and a David star.

[image]

Google research showed some simple results.

Comment: If anyone else is curious, the yellow flag on the right is that of the Identitäre Bewegung.

Comment: @Fizz: There's also a yellow Flemish flag in the back (with the black lion).

Comment: Whether this question and others like it are on-topic is [being discussed on Meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4729/19301)

Comment: @MSalters: that one can't be seen too well in the frame, but it seem to lack the red bits, which seem to suggest it's a flag of the ["Flemish Movement"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flemish_Movement) rather than one of the other variations on the [Flag of Flanders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Flanders).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The angle of the photo is pretty bad, but the star isn't actually David's star (despite the six points): note the steeper angles. Also there is a smaller star-like symbol "under" the crescent. All these point to the [Coat of arms of Halle an der Saale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_and_crescent#Municipal_coats_of_arms), Germany (1327), or at least something derived from that.

[image]

Actually Wikipedia even gives the flag [in the city article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halle_(Saale)), which has different proportions between the two stars, matching what's seen in the photo:

[image]

Comment: For curiosity's sake, see also [Leliwa coat of arms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leliwa_coat_of_arms) which--in some but not all renderings--uses a star geometrically more similar to David's star inside a crescent.

Comment: Note that the town is simply called “Halle” nowadays.

Comment: @Relaxed Some people add "an der Saale" to distinguish it from the (smaller) [Halle (Westf)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halle_(Westfalen)).

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Honestly never heard it called that. If you don't know it or there is any ambiguity, it would be just as common to add “in Sachsen-Anhalt”. If you want to distinguish with the city in Belgium, you would probably say “Halle in Germany”. Meanwhile the name is still “Halle” and that's what it's most commonly called.

Comment: What does the number "(1327)" mean? The year when that coat of arms was introduced? I think this might give the impression that this is somehow an old or antiquated symbol. It's not. [It's on the official website of the city](http://www.halle.de/en/Home/).

Comment: @Philipp: I suppose it's the year when it first appeared. I'm guessing it's based on older heraldry. Halle existed around year 1300 (also) according to Wikipedia. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einwohnerentwicklung_von_Halle_(Saale)#Von_1300_bis_1900

Comment: @Relaxed I guess the more official name is "Halle (Saale)", the "an der" is just a way of pronouncing the parentheses. (You can see this name being used on the city's website too: http://www.halle.de/en/Home/ or https://www.halle.de/de/Verwaltung/Presseportal/Nachrichten/?NewsID=46350&Page=1 – the name is always followed by the `(Saale)`.) Of course, where there is no ambiguity, people omit it.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Everybody can read that in Wikipedia and that's also what the signs at the train station say. You seem to be discovering it step by step but I was fully aware of it when I wrote my original comment. “Halle (Saale)” is not a name people use, “Halle” is how “Halle (Saale)” is actually pronounced in the real world. What my examples were meant to show is that things you add when there is some ambiguity (which would seldom happen) are not part of the name.

Comment: That's markedly different from, say, Frankfurt am Main, where the full name is both official and frequently heard.

Comment: @Relaxed "Halle an der Saale" *is* commonly used, even if you deny it. I guess it depends a bit on the region you are in. But I regularly hear that on the Radio when there is a need to talk about one of the Halles.

Comment: @Polygnome That's possible, where are you located? In Westphalia? I am not saying nobody ever said “Halle an der Saale” (or used any other qualifier, as discussed above), it's even an older name of the city. What I am saying is that Halle is the actual name of the city and much more common, for the need to distinguish would be rare in general.

Comment: The more interesting question would be why this flag of the city of Halle appears in this context. Is the bar this documentary was about located in Halle? Is there some right wing group that uses that flag?

Comment: @Hulk: I know nothing about the documentary alas... Might want to ask the OP that. In general though, the extreme right is more active in (former) Eastern Germany, where Halle (Salle) is located.

Comment: Coats of arms are not logos: it's quite normal for emblazonments of the same arms to differ a lot. I wouldn't read too much into the steepness of the angles or the relative sizes of the two stars. That falls within the artist's choice.

Comment: @Relaxed Counterpoint to Frankfurt: I currently live about an hour by train away and basically never do I hear the qualifier *am Main*. I do agree that that I almost never hear *Halle* with an additional qualifier either. And just for completeness' sake: The Kreisstadt of my hometown carries an i. OB. (in Oberbayern) in its official name and that qualifier is also almost never spoken.